# How to perform sql injection test on an iOS app on a non-jail broken iphone 5?

Tags: ios, iphone, testing, sql-injection, security-testing

I have been involved in security testing of iOS apps lately. The app is running on iOS on iphone 5. This app is similar to **"bookmyshow"** app, where user can book events occurring at various places in the city.

I need to perform sql injection testing & report security bugs if any. I am literally clueless about this task. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Note:** The device is a normal iphone 5 & jail-broken device is not available.

Thanks in advance,

Novice_Student

Comment: what is the database you want to do this on ? and where is it located ?

Comment: @Niko - The app is installed on my iOS 5. I am not sure about the database this app is using or where is this located. I might be sounding quite novice, but all I have is this iphone 5 with this app installed.
Could you please let me know how to know about database & its location on my phone?

Answer (score 3):

You can read this documents:

- [IOS Application Security Testing Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/IOS_Application_Security_Testing_Cheat_Sheet)
- [Pentesting iOS Applications](http://www.slideshare.net/jasonhaddix/pentesting-ios-applications)
- [How to prevent SQL Injection in iOS apps?](http://technet.weblineindia.com/mobile/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-ios-apps/2/)
- [iOS Application (In)Security](https://www.mdsec.co.uk/research/iOS_Application_Insecurity_wp_v1.0_final.pdf)
- [iOS Applications Different Developers Same Mistakes](https://reverse.put.as/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/Syscan-2012-iOS-Applications-and-the-Lion-City-Presso.pdf)

You must to know what you need to check. it's helpful image:

[image]

> The app is installed on my iOS 5. I am not sure about the database
>   this app is using or where is this located. I might be sounding quite
>   novice, but all I have is this iphone 5 with this app installed. Could
>   you please let me know how to know about database & its location on my
>   phone?
>   I need to perform sql injection testing & report security bugs if any.

I think you need check if there are sql injections. On image it's on right side.

You can simply connect to wi-fi network, where your server/computer can record request from your app. For example use there some HTTP proxy / HTTP monitor that enables for you to view all of the HTTP a HTTPS traffic between app and the Internet. At first link there are tools.

Comment: Thanks for your comments bro. Most of the tools require a jailbroken device. But as I previously mentioned, jailbreaking is not allowed in my case. 
As far as the traffic  is concerned, I am able to see the request & response data using **Fiddler** tool.
But I don't know how to check for sql injections from this point.

Comment: It's sample How to Capture iPhone and iPad Network Traffic With Charles:  http://www.moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-capture-iphone-and-ipad-network-traffic-with-charles/ PS: You can use anather proxy on Windows/Linux/MacOs

Comment: That was really helpful Valeriy, now that I am able to capture to traffic, could you guide me on **how to perform sql injection check**?

Comment: You must to know how app code access to server. Maybe this is json. then you need detect all possible variables and send your for sql injection. Maybe site, where this app is connected has api like github. With explanation: https://developer.github.com/v3/